# Regex in Excel VBA - Part two

Tags: regex, vba, excel

This is an extension from [Regular Expressions in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149975)

I have come up with additional matches that I believe are out of scope from my original question. Here is my existing code:

```
  Sub ImportFromDTD()

  Dim sDTDFile As Variant
  Dim ffile As Long
  Dim sLines() As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Reg1 As RegExp
  Dim M1 As MatchCollection
  Dim M As Match
  Dim myRange As Range

  Set Reg1 = New RegExp

  ffile = FreeFile

  sDTDFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("DTD Files,*.XML", , _
  "Browse for file to be imported")

  If sDTDFile = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)


  Open sDTDFile For Input Access Read As #ffile
    Lines = Split(Input$(LOF(ffile), #ffile), vbNewLine)
  Close #ffile

  Cells(1, 2) = "From DTD"
  J = 2

  For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)

    'Debug.Print "Line"; i; "="; Lines(i)

    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "\<\!ELEMENT\s+(\w+)\s+\((#\w+|(\w+)\+)\)\s+\>"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
    End With

    If Reg1.Test(Lines(i)) Then
      Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(Lines(i))
      For Each M In M1
        sExtract = M.SubMatches(2)
        If Len(sExtract) = 0 Then sExtract = M.SubMatches(0)
        sExtract = Replace(sExtract, Chr(13), "")
        Cells(J, 2) = sExtract
        J = J + 1
        'Debug.Print sExtract
      Next M
    End If
  Next i

  Set Reg1 = Nothing

  End Sub
```

Here is an excerpt from my file:

```
<!ELEMENT ProductType  (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT Invoices  (InvoiceDetails+) >  
<!ELEMENT Deal  (DealNumber,DealType,DealParties) >
<!ELEMENT DealParty  (PartyType,CustomerID,CustomerName,CentralCustomerID?,
           LiabilityPercent,AgentInd,FacilityNo?,PartyReferenceNo?,
           PartyAddlReferenceNo?,PartyEffectiveDate?,FeeRate?,ChargeType?) >
<!ELEMENT Deals  (Deal*) >
```

currently, I'm matching:

```
extract ProductType
<!ELEMENT ProductType  (#PCDATA) >
extract InvoiceDetails
<!ELEMENT Invoices  (InvoiceDetails+) >
```

I also need to extract the following:

```
 Extract Deal
 <!ELEMENT Deal  (DealNumber,DealType,DealParties) >

 Extract DealParty the ?,CR are throwing me off
 <!ELEMENT DealParty  (PartyType,CustomerID,CustomerName,CentralCustomerID?,
           LiabilityPercent,AgentInd,FacilityNo?,PartyReferenceNo?,
           PartyAddlReferenceNo?,PartyEffectiveDate?,FeeRate?,ChargeType?) >

 Extract Deal
 <!ELEMENT Deals  (Deal*) >
```

Comment: @pnuts I think your edits are worse than my original question.

Comment: This question is nearly exactly the same as my first one but in more detail I got 4 upvotes for that one. I have 2 down votes and a close on this one? In what universe does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but (sorry, I don't have VBA at hand now, so this is VBS, you will have to adapt something)

```
Option Explicit

Dim fileContents    
    fileContents = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("input.xml").ReadAll

Dim matches    
    With New RegExp
        .Multiline = True 
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "<!ELEMENT\s+([^\s>]+)\s+([^>]*)\s*>"
        Set matches = .Execute( fileContents )
    End With

Dim match
    For Each match in matches
        WScript.Echo match.Submatches(0)
        WScript.Echo match.Submatches(1)
        WScript.Echo "---------------------------------------"
    Next
```

As I see it, your main problem is trying to match a multiline regular expression against a separate set of lines one line at a time instead of matching it against the full text.

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you!